# Change in custom options the file size requirement from maximum to minimum

Tags: magento-1.9, image, product-images

I want to change the custom options the file size requirement from maximum to minimum.

[image]

I want that the system check the minimum size but not the maximum size. Example:

- If I write in system 1000px x 1000px
- If I upload a picture 800 x 800 than it must throw the error
- But the picture is greater than 1000px x 1000px than can this uploaded.

Comment: ich möchte wenn d. Kunde in einem artikel bild hochladet sollte das System minimale pixel überprüfen.und das magento überprüft standardmäßig die maximale werte.ich möchte das system die

ZB. wenn ich im adminbereich 100x100 angebe.und d. Kunde sollte nicht kleiner als 100x100 hochladen zu können.

Mfg

Comment: Hi bydna and welcome to MAgeOverflow. Please write english, because the platform language is english. We are eager to help, but we don't solve your problem here. So please start resolving it by your self and if you find a problem, explain it and we help.

Answer (score 0):

In the method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option_Type_File::_validateUploadedFile` there is this code that checks if the image is under the values set in the admin:

```
    $_dimentions = array();
    if ($option->getImageSizeX() > 0) {
        $_dimentions['maxwidth'] = $option->getImageSizeX();
    }
    if ($option->getImageSizeY() > 0) {
        $_dimentions['maxheight'] = $option->getImageSizeY();
    }
    if (count($_dimentions) > 0) {
        $upload->addValidator('ImageSize', false, $_dimentions);
    }
```

You can try changing `maxwidth` and `maxheight` to `minwidth` and `minheight`