# Limit the size of a file upload

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

I using a custom option on the product detail a type file

I need limit this input to 10MB

It can be done from magento options or should I modify some file

Thank you

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40729/change-in-custom-options-the-file-size-requirement-from-maximum-to-minimum check this maybe helpfull

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how you setup the upload but in PHP you can do stuff like this:

```
if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {
    $maxsize    = 2097152;

    if(($_FILES['uploaded_file']['size'] >= $maxsize)) {
        exit('File too large. File must be less than 2 megabytes.');
    }
}
```

On top of that you can use `php.ini` settings to limit the upload size:

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

Comment: No where is the php file upload file, but the other solution seems useful I have to contact the server administrator to see if you can do it from php.ini
Whether it will comment that this was

Comment: The first part of my comment is related to the php upload file. You've got to find the related controller and adapt the code I pasted to your specific case.